# How to access the mesh when the 3D object is loaded during runtime in Aframe?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh, aframe, 3d-model

When 3D object is loaded during runtime in Aframe, how to access the mesh information?

I have loaded the 3D Model with:

```
targetObj = document.createElement('a-obj-model');
targetObj.setAttribute('gltf-model', '#whatever_model');
```

and the following is how I tried to get the mesh information:

```
targetObj.addEventListener('loaded', function () {
    console.log(targetObj.hasLoaded);
    console.log(targetObj.getObject3D('mesh'));
});
```

When I do this, I see the `targetObj` is loaded, however, the mesh information is `undefined`.

Comment: nvm, I found the solution. Instead of "loaded" event, use "model-loaded".  Reference: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/obj-model.js

Comment: You can post it as an anwser - someone may find it useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(or model-loaded event):

```
targetObj.addEventListener('object3dset', function (evt) {
  if (evt.detail.name !== 'mesh') { return; }
  targetObj.getObject3D('mesh');
});
```